# Openfire plugin servlet

Tags: java, ios, servlets, openfire

I'm trying to write an OpenFire plugin to support Apple Push Notifications. My plan is that I want the client (iOS app) to send its token to my plugin servlet once the user logs in.


So far all I have seen people doing is add servlets for the Admin console, but my servlet is not for the admin console, it's supposed to be for my actual chat client. I just want the client to send me the token so that I can store it mapped to the logged in user, so keep in mind that I need to be able to get the currently logged in username. Does anyone know how to go about that? I'm new to OpenFire so please be patient. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing tons of research, it so happens that Servlets is not what I was supposed to use at all. Instead, for this kind of scenario I should be using IQ Packets, which are part of the XMPP standard. Everything revolves around `IQHandler`: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/3.8.2/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/handler/IQHandler.html